# Removing a list of words from sentences using lambda

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a dataframe, where each row corresponds to a string. I want to remove certain words from these strings - here is how I do it using a lambda-function:

```
def remove_words(s):    
    return s.apply(lambda x: [x for x in x if x not in ["name", "is", "m"]])

s = pd.DataFrame({"s":["Hi my name is Joe", "Hi my name is Hannah", "Hi my name is Brian"]})
remove_words(s.s)
```

This doesn't produce the correct result as it removes the `m`'s from all the words:

```
0        [H, i,  , y,  , n, a, e,  , i, s,  , J, o, e]
1    [H, i,  , y,  , n, a, e,  , i, s,  , H, a, n, ...
2    [H, i,  , y,  , n, a, e,  , i, s,  , B, r, i, ...
Name: s, dtype: object
```

The desired result I want is, however,

```
0        ["Hi my Joe"]
1    ["Hi my Hannah"]
2    ["Hi my Brian"]
Name: s, dtype: object
```

- so it should only remove an `m` in the case where it is a separate letter in the string. Is it possible to do this with lambdas?

---

Please see this counterexample when using regex:

```
regex = '|'.join((' %s ' % word for word in ["in", "out", "between"])) 
test = pd.DataFrame({"s": ["hello in out between inner in"]})
test.s.str.replace(regex, " ")
```

This doesn't weed out all `out` nor `in`

```
0    hello out inner in
Name: s, dtype: object
```

Comment: `lambda x: [x for x in x if x not in...`  You know you can use any variable names you want, right?  Naming both your lambda parameter and your iterating variable as `x` is a great way to confuse readers.

Answer (score 2):

Using `.apply()` and a lambda is a bit inefficient for this case.  Pandas [string methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html) are built specifically for this:

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series(["Hi my name is Joe", "Hi my name is Hannah", "Hi my name isn't Brian"])   
>>> words = ['name', 'is']
>>> regex = r' *\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words))
>>> s.str.replace(regex, '').str.strip()
0       Hi my Joe
1    Hi my Hannah
2     Hi my isn't Brian
dtype: object
```

Why not use `.apply()` here?  This method is a way of mapping a (native Python) callable to each element of a Pandas object one-by-one.  In generally, it can lead to doing more work at a slower pace than necessary.  For example, in `["".join([x for x in x if x not in ["name", "is"]])]`, you have (1) a list comprehension, (2) `.split()`, and (3) a join operation for each individual "cell".

With your updated case:

```
>>> s2 = pd.Series(["hello in out between inner in"])
>>> words = ['in', 'out', 'between']
>>> regex = r' *\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words)) 
>>> s2.str.replace(regex, '').str.strip()
0    hello inner
dtype: object
```

The `str.strip()` is built to deal with cases where the result would otherwise be padded with whitespace on either or both sides.  Using `.str` methods should be pretty quick even if they are method-chained.

Comment: I like this approach, but it doesn't seem to work in all cases. I made an example in the OP where it doesn't remove all instances of unwanted words

Comment: thanks for updating your answer. there's 1 more _potential_ case i've highlighted where the match happens on the end of the string, example `re.sub(r' *\bHi\b| *\bname\b| *\bis\b', '', 'Hi my name is Joe')` will then need to be stripped of the space at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

using regex [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
import re
# construct the regex pattern
words = ['name', 'is']
pattern = re.compile(r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(words)))

# apply the function on the series
s.s.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub(pattern, '', x)))
```

re.sub is used twice, first to remove the words, next to replace extra spaces.

outputs:

```
0       Hi my Joe
1    Hi my Hannah
2     Hi my Brian
```

`\b` is the regex pattern for word-boundary. `\b(name|is|a)\b` will match the following, matches indicated by a strike-through

<s>a</s> rose by any other <s>name</s>

as you can see, even single letter words are properly matched. However, there is 1 more issue that the above solution hasn't addressed yet.

A match at the end of the sentence will leave a single space which isn't cleaned up by `re.sub(r'\s+', ' ',...`. so, it may be necessary to `strip` spaces as well. This would depend on your data

With that note, the final solution becomes:

```
s.s.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\s+', ' ', re.sub(pattern, '', x)).strip())
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably?

```
def remove_words(s):    
    return s.apply(lambda x: ["".join([x for x in x if x not in ["name", "is"]])])
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the list comprehension over the string (it will return each character). do a split on the sentence first like:

```
def remove_words(s, stop_words):    
    return s.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(w for w in x.split() if w not in stop_words))
```

if you want to return the sentence inside a list:

```
def remove_words_return_list(s, stop_words):    
    return s.apply(lambda x: [' '.join(w for w in x.split() if w not in stop_words)])
```

call it like:

```
remove_words(s, ['name', 'is', 'm'])
remove_words_return_list(s, ['name', 'is', 'm'])
```